# Is it possible to provide a service similar to Yousendit from within my SAAS site using google drive API

Tags: cakephp

I would like to provide a file send service from within cloud-accounts where users can send any type of large file to their clients with a download link. When they click the link they are presented with the users logo etc to project a professional image and controls for downloading their file. Does the API allow this type of integration. The site was build using Cakephp.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with CakePHP. This questions is... pretty generic. You can implement any storage provider. I've written [a CakePHP plugin](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) that uses the Gaufrette storage library as base and makes it accessible the CakePHP-way and adds some additional features. [There is no Google Drive adapter](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/tree/master/src/Gaufrette/Adapter) yet but its easy to write an adapter.

But I do not think google drive is your right choice for this:

> The Drive API is welcome, but it is very restricted. The restrictions
>   are necessary to an extent to ensure the security of the users' data,
>   but they also serve to limit the potential to misuse Google's cloud
>   storage. For example, if fast programmatic access was possible you
>   could create an app that automatically merged a number of Drive
>   accounts together to provide (potentially free) aggregated storage.
>   The limitations seem to restrict you to creating web apps that use
>   Drive as their document storage, and don't allow you to build storage
>   utilities, which is where there is scope for real innovation.

[Source](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/141-cloud-computing/4117-google-drive-api-an-opportunity.html)